# Bootstrap4 Datetime picker With Angular 5 Required

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Any sources for using Bootstrap4 Datetime picker with angular5 I have tried some but they support bootstrap3 only and my angular theme is developed over bootstrap4

I tried https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker this but it is also working only for bootstrap 3 not for 4.

Comment: Look here https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIjpT0tfON3wIVqh6tBh1ZhA7jEAAYASAAEgKuAvD_BwE#/datepicker

Comment: I need datetime picker this is only datepicker.

Comment: You could use both components, there is also a timepicker on the same page

Comment: I want on the same input

Answer (score 1):

This works with angular5 and bootstrap3

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker

To gete my problems solved i have to install one more package to support for bootstrap 4

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker